# Why is my bibliography unnumbered?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

Consider the following reference entry:

```
@article{hurwicz1,
    title = "Optimality and informational efficiency in resource allocation processes",
    author = "Leonid Hurwicz",
    journal = "Mathematical Methods in the Social Sciences",
    year = "1960",
    publisher = "Stanford University Press",
    editor = "Kenneth J. Arrow and S. Karlin and P. Suppes",
    pages = "27 -- 46",
    url = "https://doi.org/10.1017%2Fcbo9780511752940.014"
}
```

Further, consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,sortcites=true,language=british]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography.

% BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS

\addbibresource{References.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{3\itemsep}
\AtBeginBibliography{ 
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}%

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  phdthesis = {PhD\addabbrvspace Thesis}
}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

\cite{hurwicz1}

\raggedright
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\emergencystretch=1em
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the output, the bibliography is not numbered. I do not know what bit in my MWE is causing this.

[image: Output screenshot]

**Can anybody help me achieve a `[1]` before the bibliography entry?**

Thank you all very much for your time.

**EDIT**: While Manuel’s answer does work, it changes `Hurwicz, 1960` to `[1]`. I’d like to have numbers in my References, but I’d like to keep `Hurwicz, 1960` instead of `[1]`. *Any clue on how to achieve that?*

Comment: You have `authoryear-comp` set as the style, choose `numeric` (or `numeric-comp`) instead.

Comment: For future reference, please read and follow the recommendations on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407 for providing a better MWE.

Comment: If your in-text citations are of the form "author year" it is absolutely not recommended to have a numeric bibliography. The numbers are superfluous as they have non connection to anything else in the document and they visually distract from the author name and year of the entry, which makes the bibliography list very hard to navigate.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @moewe you are actually right… Hence, I will probably accept the answer I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change `\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,sortcites=true,language=british]{biblatex}` to `\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=numeric-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,sortcites=true,language=british]{biblatex}`.
- The option `style` is changed.
- Please read and follow [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407) for future related questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for helping me provide better MWEs in the future. Unfortunately, while your achieves what I want in the References section, it also changes `Hurwicz, 1960` to `[1]`. I’d like to keep `Hurwicz, 1960`.